# Website Dimension Changes

Tags: html, css

Hi I am working on making a website. The problem is the dimensions of the website change on the computer. The computer screens are different sizes, and some are different browsers. For instance the navigation bar will change width, and it will also overlap on some computers. It also will outline images on one computer, and it is using Internet Explorer, but on another computer that is running Chrome (And Different Screen Size) the images are not outlined. I do not know why this is, please help!

**My HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    Drippr
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Drippr</h1>
    <div id="navbar">

        <a href="http://drippr.me/" class="boxtext">
            <div id="box1">
                <p> Dripps </p>
                <img src="http://drippr.me/images/paper.svg" style="height: 40px">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="http://drippr.me/" class="boxtext">
            <div id="box2">
                <p> Bucket </p>
                <img src="http://drippr.me/images/bucket.svg" style="height: 40px">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="http://drippr.me/" class="boxtext">
            <div id="box3">
                <p> Settings </p>
                <img src="http://drippr.me/images/settings.svg" style="height: 40px">
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>

    <div id="hometop">
        <ul id="hometoplist">
            <li>TEST</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="bubbles">
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="bubbles">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS:**

```
#title {
    color: #1c63ff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: 45%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#navbar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #D1ECFF;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -10;
    top: -1;
    border: 2px solid #A1C6FF;
}

.boxtext {
    color: darkblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;

}

.boxtext:hover {
    color: darkblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#box1 {
    height: 18%;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #5CBDFF;
    border: 2px solid #3385FF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    top: 5px;
    margin-left: 6.5px;
    position: absolute;
}

#box1:hover {
    background-color: #79AEFF
}

#box2 {
    height: 18%;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #5CBDFF;
    border: 2px solid #3385FF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    top: 145px;
    margin-left: 6.5px;
    position: absolute;
}

#box2:hover {
    background-color: #79AEFF
}

#box3 {
    height: 18%;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #5CBDFF;
    border: 2px solid #3385FF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    top: 285px;
    margin-left: 6.5px;
    position: absolute;
}

#box3:hover {
    background-color: #79AEFF
}

#hometop {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D7D7D7;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
}

.bubbles {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #99C2FF;
    border: 2px solid #1975FF;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 160px;
}

#hometoplist {
    text-align: right;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: px;
}

#footer {
}
```

Comment: A given "pixel size" will appear larger (at smaller resolutions), and smaller (at higher resolutions).  For example, a 100x100 pixel image might look *HUGE* at 800x600 ... and the *SAME* image could appear *TINY* at 1280x1024.  I suspect that's the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your navigation bar issue is due to different screen resolutions on different displays. Since the smallest width for the majority of users is >= 1024 px, try setting a width of 1024 px for your site's `<body>` or a div wrapper around everything in the body of the site.

Also, I recall IE has images bordered by default...try adding to your css:

```
img {
    border:0;
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: How could I fix this so it does not matter on the screen resolution? Thank You  [PS images fixed!]

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, one thing you could do is place all of your site's rendered content (i.e., things that a user sees on your site) within a div of width 1024px...typically a div like this is placed right after the opening body tag and closed right before the closing body tag